# Why is computer making noise while gaming after installing new RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory, noise, gaming

I looked for an answer for my query on this site but couldn't find any. So here's my problem;

I'm running a core 2 duo @ 2.6ghz with an ATI 6450-1GB DDR3 on windows 7 32bit. I had 2 GB of memory and decided to upgrade. Yesterday I installed 4gb (2x2) of new transcend ram (ddr2 JM800QLU-2G 800MHZ).

Now the computer is making a motor like loud noise every time I play a game (e.g. far cry 3, crysis 2 and 3, inversion etc). The computer did make this noise before I installed the new memory, but it wasn't this loud and frequent. Now it just keeps happening while gaming. I am not sure from which component the sound is coming from (its not the fan though, I am sure about that).

What could be causing it?

Comment: It sounds like the CPU fan is starting to fail.  The fact it wasn't happening a few days ago doesn't mean your memory upgrade is to blame.  If it is the fan then the memory upgrade isn't to blame.

Comment: hi mate. thanks for your reply. i asked if it has anything to do with the memory because the noise is considerably louder after installing it. it rarely made noise before. so you see,i was wondering if it has anything to do with the ram and graphics card speeds or something like that because i have read on a lot of sites about the clock speed or something like that not being set properly in BIOS after installing the new memory. it surely doesnt sound like the fan. any ideas about the bios settings?

Comment: Does it still make the noise if you revert back to the previous RAM configuration?

Comment: @MaxiMays - Memory is unable to make noise there are no moving parts.  The only explanation is they generate more heat, and now your CPU fan is working harder then before, but this would again point to your CPU fan failing.

Comment: @charlierb. no mate, it doesnt make as much noise when i insert the old ram which is 2 gb. i have another 2 stick of dynet,2 gb each too. when i insert them, it makes noise again. so heres the thing. when i insert 4 gb, the cooler master is making the noise. when i insert 2 gb, it doesnt make as much noise. i donno what to make of that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you didn't bump any fan shrouds into the range of fan blades in the process of trying to get RAM chips to click into the locked position.  Specifically on the graphics card if it tends to be worse when gaming, when more demand/heat is on that card.

Comment: i sure was careful while installing the ram. didnt bump or touch anything.

Comment: Can you explain the noise a little more (whir? clicking? hum? high pitch? low pitch?) or narrow down a region in the computer it's coming from?

Comment: it seems to be coming from the middle. and its like a grinding noise. medium high pitch. like a car running. not whirring like the fan.

Comment: could it be that the cpu is not able to allot enough memory to the gpu? did any settings get altered when the ram was increased i wonder.

Comment: @MaxiMays No, that's not the issue. The noise you describe is going to be something that has a moving part: CPU Fan, GPU Fan, Case Fan, or harddrive. If you don't know which it is, pull the case out so that you can access it, take the side off, and start gaming until the noise happens. Then, look to see what is making the noise. Don't touch anything while the system is on.

Comment: hmm,thanks for clearing up my doubt Darth. i will try your suggestion and get back here tomorrow as its 1 am here and am about to sleep. will do what you said in the morning and let you know. man i hope it isnt the hard drive though. thanks again!

Comment: Yeah it could be something as simple as a cable now rubbing your cpu fan etc.  Panhandel is right for sure.

Comment: ok guys. i pulled the case out and i think its the cooler master on the mobo thats making the noise. was fine when i was using the comp without gaming. but the noise started very loudly when i started gaming. so what do i do? replace the cooler master? or its gonna be the same even if i put in a new one? what could be causing it to make noise while gaming? the thing is, like i said, the noise wasnt so loud before i installed the new memory. so is the higher memory conflicting with the gpu or somehting?

Comment: for those saying that ram cant make noise, you must think i am pretty dim.you made me laugh though. of course i know it cant make noise and doesnt have moving parts!. really now. lol.